# How to get session id in trigger without using UserInfo class?

Tags: trigger, webservices, session

I have to create PDF file in trigger upon user approval through email. Since Getcontent() method is not allowed in trigger, I am using weservice to create PDF.

As user is approving through email only, it is not possible to get the session id to pass webservice.

Is there any way to get session id?

(Or)

is there any other way to create PDF from trigger?

Note: I am using PDF vf page in some other button also, to maintain integrity using the same page.

- I am using standard Approval process email approval functionality
- PDF will be stored as attachment to the record

Comment: Where do you need the PDF to go to after its been generated? Does it need to be stored or emailed?

Comment: are you using an email handler to parse the approval email or using the standard functionality?

Comment: Does it have to be trigger? Can't you add new email alert to the approval? Would need an email template which can be a Visualforce template with PDF attached...

Comment: @eyescream thinking exactly the same, hence the question... :-)

Comment: I do have a cunning plan if it still has to be done in a trigger though... ;-)

Comment: I have update the my question with more notes

Comment: Could you not just generate the PDF in a @future method called from the trigger?

Comment: in future method also we cannot use getContent or getcontentaspdf methods.

Comment: I found another work around to create PDF.. but the pdf is empty.. I have created a Visualforce tempalte which has pdf as an attachement and which is part of approval process... using email service i am process this email to get the attachement.. but the attachment is empty.... it works fine when i was using with some other workflow which is not during the approval.... any idea why the PDF is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by getting session id using Partner webservice in future Method which is invoked in trigger.